# Invalidate numbers with leading zeros with Validators.pattern(..)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a validator that uses a regex pattern `/^[1-9][0-9]*$/` to only allow numbers without leading zeros.

This can expression can easily be tested like so:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/.test("04") // returns false
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/.test("40") // returns true
```

The ReactiveForm is defined as:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  'sum': new FormControl(null, Validators.pattern(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/))
})
```

And the template is

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="number" formControlName="sum" style="display:block; margin-bottom:10px;">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I use this in a ReactiveForm, entering a the number `04` should add the class `ng-invalid` to the field and mark the form as invalid.

Instead the form is marked valid and the class `ng-valid` are added to the field.

I reproduced it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z2ggrf)

Comment: Looks fine to me. Can you reproduce with a stackblizt?

Comment: What is the issue? What numbers are failing validation?

Comment: You need to define what is valid and what is invalid, possibly providing examples of each if it is not straightforward.

Comment: @theMayer, I have reproduced the issue. See an update question. I think the question should be opened.

Comment: Yes this is a real issue. I can reproduce. Please vote to reopen.

Comment: From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). ***Pattern validation*** - *<input type="number"> elements do not support use of the pattern attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex pattern. The rationale for this is that number inputs won't be valid if they contain anything except numbers, and you can constrain the minimum and maximum number of valid digits using the min and max attributes (as explained above).* By the way, does the leading zero affect the actual input value? I would think that it has no effect on it.

Comment: @alexander.sivak change the <input type="number"> to <input type="text"> 

The reason for this is that when these are evaluated as numbers -- then implicitly converted back to string for the validation -- the leading zeros are stripped off. It would be the same as /^[1-9]\d*$/.test(04) -- String(04) // returns 4

Comment: @alexander.sivak As Martin already said, the leading zero is stripped. you can see the issue if you add `{{f.value | json}}` to your template or log your form when you submit.

Comment: Please avoid putting answers in the comments. If you have an answer, then it is good to leave as an answer.

Comment: @theMayer - We put answers in comments when answers are not allowed. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears that some of the documentation on this feature may have been missed, as suggested in the comments.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number):

> **Pattern validation** - `<input type="number">` elements do not support use of the pattern attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex pattern. The rationale for this is that number inputs won't be valid if they contain anything except numbers, and you can constrain the minimum and maximum number of valid digits using the min and max attributes (as explained above).

The question that I'm left with is "why would you want to do this." If you're trying to constrain a valid input to just numbers, that can be achieved by using the `input type="number"`. If, however, you're trying to force the user to type in a certain pattern for unknown reasons, it is a virtual guarantee that your users will hate your software.  Instead, if a user input is understandable by the computer, then you should accept it. If it isn't, you should request user clarification, explaining why. It is unclear what the end-goal is here, but it seems that this is a case of [overzealous form validation](https://blog.prototypr.io/ux-best-practices-of-form-validation-ddb8a0df14fd).

Comment: "why would you want to do this." you did not answer the question

Comment: @Michal- Did you read the first half of my answer?

Comment: I just posted my own answer.

Comment: You explained how things work but you didn't solve the problem. Validating input type number with leading zeros would be complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution here would be creating custom `OnlyDigits` directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[onlyDigits]',
})
export class OnlyDigitsDirective {
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(ev: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = ev.target as HTMLInputElement;
    input.value = String(input.value.replace(/\D+/g, ''));
  }
}
```

And then I believe you can keep the pattern validator:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  'sum': new FormControl(null, Validators.pattern(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/))
})
```

and optionally you can add HTML validation so that the user can't input more than 2 numbers:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="sum" style="display:block; margin-bottom:10px;" onlyDigits maxLength="2">
```

You can also set the input mode to `numeric` if you want the user mobile experience to be better:

https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/